# how to resolve optional url path using ng-resource

Tags: rest, angularjs

There are restful APIs, for instance:

- `/players` - to get list for all players
- `/players{/playerName}` - to get info for specific player

and I already have a function using ng-resource like:

```
function Play() {
  return $resource('/players');
}
```

Can I reuse this function for specific player like:

```
function Play(name) {
  return $resource('/players/:name', {
    name: name
  });
}
```

so I want to...

- send request for `/players` if I didn't pass `name` parameter.
- send request for `/players/someone` if I passed `name` parameter with `someone`

Otherwise, I have to write another function for specific play?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using ngResource it's very, very simple (it's basically a two-liner). You don't need even need to create any custom actions here*.**

I've posted a working Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FaPMGA2LN6n3GIgp9vH6?p=preview) (just open Chrome Developer tools and go to the *Network* tab to see the results).

#### Service body:

```
return $resource('/users/:id/:name', { id:'@id', name: '@name' })
```

#### Controller:

```
  function( $scope, Users ){
    Users.query(); // GET /users (expects an array)
    Users.get({id:2}); // GET /users/2
    Users.get({name:'Joe'}); // GET /users/Joe
  }
```

- of course, you could, [if you really wanted to](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) :)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it. This way you don't have to write a custom resource function for each one of your endpoints, you just add it to your list resources list. I defined a list of the endpoints I wanted to use like this.

```
var constants = {
  "serverAddress": "foobar.com/",
  "resources": {
      "Foo": {
        "endpoint": "foo"
      },
      "Bar": {
        "endpoint": "bar"
      }
  }
}
```

Then created resources out of each one of them like this.

```
var service = angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource']);

var resourceObjects = constants.resources;

for (var resourceName in resourceObjects) {
  if (resourceObjects.hasOwnProperty(resourceName)) {
    addResourceFactoryToService(service, resourceName,    resourceObjects[resourceName].endpoint);
  }
}

function addResourceFactoryToService (service, resourceName, resourceEndpoint) {
  service.factory(resourceName, function($resource) {
    return $resource(
        constants.serverAddress + resourceEndpoint + '/:id',
            {
                id: '@id',
            },
            {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {id: '@id'}
            },
        }
    );
});
```

}

The nice thing about this is that it takes 2 seconds to add a new endpoint, and I even threw in a put method for you. Then you can inject any of your resources into your controllers like this.

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, Foo, Bar) {
  $scope.foo = Foo.query();
  $scope.bar = Bar.get({id:4});
}
```

Answer (score -2):

- Use Play.query() to find all players
- Use Play.get({name:$scope.name}) to find one player